# What is considered a large difference between server system times? How can I synchronize my CentOS server with Twitter?

Tags: twitter, centos, twitter-oauth

I am having problems with some oauth_token's returning as invalid from Twitter.  After doing some research I think this is due to a difference in system times between my server and Twitter's servers.  I was able to get Twitter's system time by curl'ing 'https://api.twitter.com/1/help/test.json' and checking the 'filetime'. The result: My server is 8 seconds ahead of Twitter's server.

Could this 8 seconds cause Twitter to return empty oauth_token's and if this is the problem, how do I synchronize by server's time (centos server) with Twitter's time.

Any and all help is much appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Twitter API allows a time difference of 5 minutes, so 8 seconds off really shouldn't be the problem. Of course it is important the time is correct and it is therefore recommended that you run something like ntpd. I'm however pretty much sure the issue you're having isn't related to the time. And to be honest I don't even have a clue on what you mean with empty oauth_token's. Note that once you have working oauth access keys they'll remain valid forever unless you revoke them manually.

Comment: So you are saying after I request and receive valid oauth tokens for a user, I should not try and re-request them next time they try and log into my app?

Comment: Nope, you should be able to use the same keys to authenticate that user. It becomes a different story if the keys are revoked, then the user would have to go through the whole OAuth process again.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronize your server with an official time server with `ntpdate`. Do not try to modify your time to meet another random server. Instead if the problem exist after your server has the correct time contact the people at twitter about this problem.

Comment: Ok, do you think an 8 second difference in server times could cause Twitter to reject my oauth_token? Just wondering if a few seconds difference in server times is normal, or alarming.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't know. But fix first the simple things and if the problem still exists go for the harder ones.